# Qt: open resizable window with recommended width

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

How can I open a dialog window in Qt/PyQt with a recommended size which can be shrinked and expanded ? I find only methods for setting a miniumSize, but not to set a actual size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QWidget.resize()` or `QWidget.setGeometry` should work in most cases.